# (ASP.NET) Getting Value of PlaceHolder Controls from Postback

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, forms, postback, placeholder

## How do I retrive the value of the controlls inside my placeholder AFTER post-back?

**Background Information**

I have 2 controls that were created dynamically(they are inside of a placeholder). The form submit button was also created dynamically.To clarify I am wanting to get the value of the dynamically created fields AFTER the button is pushed.

**The Problem**

When using request.form I keep getting null values. I have tried making the ClientIDMode static, but the problem persists. I have also tried to simply use the PLACEHOLDER1.FindControll method, but this also returns null

**CODE(Where I am Trying to retrieve the values of the controls)**

```
 Protected Sub submitEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles submitEdit.Click
    Dim currentClass As String = submitEdit.CssClass

    If currentClass = "hidden active" Then
        'Get Rid of Controls
        EditHeaderH1.Visible = False
        submitEdit.Visible = False
        submitEdit.CssClass = "hidden inactive"
        currentStatus.value = "updated"
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Find subject and Post Content''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Dim subjectText As String = Request.Form("editSubject")
        Dim editorText As String = Request.Form("editEditor")
        Dim editID As String = Request.Form("hiddenID")
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratnewsConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim nCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCom As New SqlCommand("UPDATE News SET Subject = @Subject, [Content] = @Content WHERE (ID = @ID)", addCon)
        addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", Server.HtmlDecode(editorText))
        addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", subjectText)
        addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", editID)

        Try
            addCon.Open()
            addCom.ExecuteNonQuery()
            addCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception



        End Try


    End If

End Sub
```

**CODE: Where the fields where initially created**

```
Public Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "editPost" Then
        plcEditor.Controls.Clear()
        GridView1.Visible = False
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        Dim ID As String = GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''CREATE Controls for Placeholder
        Dim editEditor As New CuteEditor.Editor
        Dim hiddenID As New HiddenField
        Dim subjectTXT As New TextBox
        Dim br As New Literal

        hiddenID.Value = ID
        hiddenID.ID = "hiddenID"
        editEditor.ID = "editEditor"
        editEditor.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static
        subjectTXT.ID = "editSubject"
        subjectTXT.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static
        hiddenID.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static

        

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim i As Integer = 100
        Dim editButton As New Button
        editButton.ID = String.Concat("editButton-", i)
        editButton.CommandArgument = i.ToString


        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim sbjLabel As New Label


        sbjLabel.Text = "Subject:   "

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        editEditor.AutoConfigure = CuteEditor.AutoConfigure.Simple
        br.Text = "<br/><br/>"
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(hiddenID)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(sbjLabel)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(subjectTXT)
        subjectTXT.Width = "100"
        subjectTXT.Height = "25"
        subjectTXT.CssClass = "editInput"
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(editEditor)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        plcEditor.Controls.Add(br)
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratnewsConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim nCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCon As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim addCom As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [News] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)", addCon)
        addCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)


        Dim results As SqlDataReader
        addCon.Open()
        results = addCom.ExecuteReader
        While results.Read()
            Dim editText As String = results.Item("Content")
            Dim Subject As String = results.Item("Subject")
            EditHeaderH1.InnerText = "Edit Post - " & Subject
            editEditor.Text = editText
            subjectTXT.Text = Subject
        End While
        results.Close()
        addCon.Close()

        ''BUTTON Fade-IN Effect''
        submitEdit.CssClass = "hidden active"
    End If
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to recreate your controls OnInit, with the same id's that they had before the postback. If you recreate your controls, the data will be bound to them and you should be able to access it in the button event.